# SQL Server 2014 - Merge - syntax errors

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, merge, syntax-error

I have this query with a merge statement running as a part of a larger script using foreachdb in SQL Server. I keep getting random syntax errors -

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 59
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 72
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

What is wrong with my script? When the merge runs outside the foreachdb, it runs fine without any errors. When inside the foreachdb, it fails with different errors every time.

```
USE RedshiftDatabase;


EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
'

BEGIN
USE ?;

        TRUNCATE TABLE #UnMatchedTransactions


        PRINT(''truncate complete'');


        INSERT INTO #UnMatchedTransactions
        SELECT
            DB_NAME(),
            TxnID,
            BatchID,
            DateCreated,
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            0
        FROM
            UnMatchedTransactions;

        SELECT db_name(),''done'';
        SELECT ClientName, COUNT(1) FROM #UnMatchedTransactions GROUP BY ClientName;

        CHECKPOINT;

        BEGIN TRANSACTION merge_tran


                MERGE INTO RedshiftDatabase.dbo.UnMatchedTransactions AS TARGET
                USING  #UnMatchedTransactions AS SOURCE
                ON  
                (
                    TARGET.ClientName = SOURCE.ClientName 
                AND 
                    TARGET.TxnID = SOURCE.TxnID
                AND 
                    TARGET.BatchID = SOURCE.BatchID
                )
                WHEN MATCHED AND (TARGET.DateCreated <> SOURCE.DateCreated)
                THEN
                    UPDATE SET 
                        DateCreated  = SOURCE.DateCreated, 
                        UpdatedTS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
                THEN
                INSERT ( ClientName,
                        TxnID,
                        BatchID,
                        DateCreated
                        ) 
                VALUES (SOURCE.ClientName,
                        SOURCE.TxnID,
                        SOURCE.BatchID,
                        SOURCE.DateCreated
                        )
                WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
                THEN 
                    UPDATE SET 
                            TARGET.IsDeleted = 1,
                            TARGET.UpdatedTS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                ;

        END TRANSACTION merge_tran;

        CHECKPOINT;

        SELECT db_name(),''Mergedone'';
        SELECT BL_ClientName, COUNT(1) FROM RedshiftDatabase.dbo.UnMatchedTransactions GROUP BY ClientName;

    END;
END
'
```

Comment: I wonder if during your `foreachdb` loop the temporary entity `#UnMatchedTransactions` is going out of scope because a new connection is spinning up for each iteration? -- It's been a few years since I've done anythng sql-server so take this comment with a grain of salt, but if it helps then great.

Comment: Try using brackets to enclose all object's names, and even the `?` of the variable database name.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few observation on code.

Why you are using sp_MSforeachdb? You can use CTE to list the all database name on server by using system tables and then you can write dynamic sql to iterate the list for your merge statement?

Here is proposed solution for your issue.

```
BEGIN
    USE ?;
    -- TO DO Check if table exists
    TRUNCATE TABLE #UnMatchedTransactions
    PRINT('truncate complete');
    -- To DO create #UnMatchedTransactions each time as database name changed so scope changed and table doesn't exist in new scope. Create table in each iteratation
    -- Second option use ##UnMatchedTransactions and delete row per database at the end
    INSERT INTO #UnMatchedTransactions
    SELECT
        DB_NAME(),
        TxnID,
        BatchID,
        DateCreated,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        0
    FROM
        UnMatchedTransactions;

    SELECT db_name(),'done';
    SELECT ClientName, COUNT(1) FROM #UnMatchedTransactions GROUP BY ClientName;

    CHECKPOINT;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION merge_tran
        MERGE INTO RedshiftDatabase.dbo.UnMatchedTransactions AS TARGET
        USING  #UnMatchedTransactions AS SOURCE
            ON  
            (
                TARGET.ClientName = SOURCE.ClientName 
            AND 
                TARGET.TxnID = SOURCE.TxnID
            AND 
                TARGET.BatchID = SOURCE.BatchID
            )
            WHEN MATCHED AND (TARGET.DateCreated <> SOURCE.DateCreated)
            THEN
                UPDATE SET 
                    DateCreated  = SOURCE.DateCreated, 
                    UpdatedTS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
            THEN
            INSERT ( ClientName,
                    TxnID,
                    BatchID,
                    DateCreated
                    ) 
            VALUES (SOURCE.ClientName,
                    SOURCE.TxnID,
                    SOURCE.BatchID,
                    SOURCE.DateCreated
                    )
            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
            THEN 
                UPDATE SET 
                        TARGET.IsDeleted = 1,
                        TARGET.UpdatedTS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            ;

    END TRANSACTION merge_tran;

    CHECKPOINT;

    SELECT db_name(),'Mergedone';
    SELECT BL_ClientName, COUNT(1) FROM RedshiftDatabase.dbo.UnMatchedTransactions GROUP BY ClientName;

    END;
    -- if using Second option then drop here so that temp tables cleaning would be done for each databaseuse
END
```